# How to update a variable in SKScene from GameViewController?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have added admob reward video to my app. Everything is ok with admob. However, I can't update live label after watching rewarded video. If I go another scene and come back, it is updated and shows new value.

//GameViewController.swift

```
 func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd,
                            didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
        print("Reward received with currency: \(reward.type), amount \(reward.amount).")


        GameData.shared.lives = GameData.shared.lives + 1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(GameData.shared.lives, forKey: "lives")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
```

//MainScene.swift

```
var lives = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "lives") {
        didSet{
            livesLabel?.text = "\(lives)"
        }
    }
```

//

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal recommendation would be to establish a connection via computed properties with the scene:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    var mainScene : MainScene? { return (self.view as SKView?).scene as? MainScene}
    var lives : Int
    {
        get
        {
            return mainScene?.lives ?? 0
        }
        set
        {
           mainScene?.lives = newValue
           //perhaps do some error handling if mainscne is nil
        }
   }
}
```

Then in your main scene, you control how lives writes to userdefaults

```
class MainScene : SKScene
{
    private var _lives : Int?
    var lives : Int
    {
        get
        {
            _lives = _lives ?? UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "lives")
            return _lives!
        }
        set
        {
            _lives = newValue
            UserDefaults.standard.set(_lives, forKey: "lives")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            livesLabel?.text = "\(_lives)"
        }
    }
}
```

Finally to use it, you would do:

```
 func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd,
                        didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
    print("Reward received with currency: \(reward.type), amount \(reward.amount).")

    lives += 1
}
```

We can then avoid having to deal with global variables, which means less opportunity for errors and bugs

Comment: I have an issue: Value of type 'GameViewController' has no member 'scene

Comment: my mistake, forgot to point to the view, but that is something you should have been aware of as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a few ways this can be done.

You can setup a notification and observer to fire whenever the value changes and then adjust the label accordingly.

You can use protocols, but I think that that is overly complex for this case.

The easiest is to probably just store a variable for `MainScene` in your GameViewController from when it gets instantiated.

```
private var mainScene: MainScene!

// Load the SKScene from MainScene.sks'
mainScene = MainScene(fileNamed: "MainScene")
mainScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
self.view?.presentScene(mainScene, transition)
```

if you do not have a corresponding SKS file created in the scene editor but rather load the scene via code use...

```
//load the mainScene using init created in code
mainScene = MainScene(size: self.view?.bounds.size)
mainScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
self.view?.presentScene(mainScene, transition)
```

now when you want to reference that scene from your GameViewController just use

```
GameData.shared.lives += 1
mainScene.lives = GameData.shared.lives
```

Comment: Hi Ron, it did not work. Maybe the reason that the rewarded video is initiated from the main scene. So the mainscene is already loaded.

Comment: @TomB. that shouldn't matter where it is initiated from. I would put a breakpoint on the mainScene.lives line and check that the variable is indeed your running scene